# Change Nexus default data directory

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, nexus, nexus3

How do I change Nexus OSS’s default data directory from /opt/sonartype to /data directory in Linux running on AWS? I have attached a larger volume and mounted it to /data directory so all Nexus repository data saves in /data location of Linux.

Answer (score 2):

The NXRM data directory is portable so can be moved with any cp/mv or drag and drop via the UI.

To tell NXRM where to find it, you need to update the nexus.vmoptions file located in your installation (not data) directory in the bin subfolder.  See [here](https://help.sonatype.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=5411784#ConfiguringtheRuntimeEnvironment-ConfiguringtheDataDirectory) for items you need to adjust.

Disclaimer: One thing I am unsure of is if you have the blobstore in the data directory if that's automatically picked up when you make the above adjustments or it needs a specific move.  If you do need to move it, you can find information how [here](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/235816228-Relocating-Blob-Stores).

Comment: I actually moved the default blobstore to /data directory manually and I updated the nexus.vmoptions file in bin directory with new path information. As mentioned in your second link, do I really need to work with orientdb thing as well?

Comment: @cloudify I don't think so but since I'm not 100% sure I mentioned it.  It was more "in case you still have issues, consider this".  Even if you don't have issues, someone else may find that link useful.